# Getting the values of action parameters within an action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an action that I am POSTing to from jquery:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateGroupName(int groupId, string name)
{
    authorisationRepository.UpdateGroupName(groupId, name);
}
```

This works fine with the `groupId` and `name`.  I have a few other group actions so I would like to use an authorisation attribute to make sure the person performing the change has permission to make the change.

I already have an `AuthorizationAttribute` that retrieves the `groupId` successfully on GET requests by accessing `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["groupId"]` but when it comes to POSTs it doesn't work.  The `Request.Form` is empty and so is `Request.Params`.

Here's the code I have in my authorisation attribute:

```cs
public int groupId { get; set; }

protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();

    // awesome permissions checking goes here...

    return authorized;
 }

public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    groupId = int.Parse(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["groupId"]); // this line throws an exception
    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
}
```

I have looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601572/104435) but my `Form` property is empty :(

Updated to show jquery post:

```
var serverComm = {
    post: function (url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    },
    get: function (url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: data
        });
    }
};
// some awesome code later...
serverComm.post(editGroupNameUrl, { groupId: group.id, name: newName })
```

Comment: And the parameter is as Form parameter? Is there a chance it's on the QueryString?

Comment: QueryString is empty. And what do you mean "is as Form parameter"? You can see my action in the top code example

Comment: could you post the form code?

Comment: Updated post to show jquery posting the data

Comment: Are you sure JSON.stringify(data) is needed? I think you just need to put the json object representing the data

Comment: MVC still gets the data. The parameters in the action get filled in as expected so it's not a problem with stringify

Comment: How's your Request.Post and Request.QueryString inside the action? are empty too?

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  That is blank also.  Have I done something wrong? Is there a better way to write my action?

Comment: Try without the stringify. I guess MVC is understanding another way of binding besides the request parameter -> action parameter. I guess it's understanding the json posted. JQuery, if you pass just the data object (without stringify) will post each field as a request parameter (at least, I think so). It's easy to try :)

Comment: Good news, it works! I commented out the setting of the contentType and removed the stringify and `Form` now contains my two parameters! I didn't think that changing the contentType would have any effect.  Would you like to write an answer so I can mark it correct and give you some brownie points? :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are sending your request as a JSON string. So there are no request parameters in the POST body and you cannot fetch them in the `Request.Params`.

So instead of:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["groupId"]
```

use:

```
filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("groupId").AttemptedValue
```

This will query the value provider (in your case the JsonValueProvider) to obtain the corresponding value send by the client.

Answer (score 1):

Try without the stringify. I guess MVC is understanding another way of binding besides the request parameter -> action parameter. I guess it's understanding the json posted. JQuery, if you pass just the data object (without stringify) will post each field as a request parameter (at least, I think so). It's easy to try :)