# How do I get ActionParameters in OnActionExecuted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I'm building an history of the action a user called. For this I need all the parameters in the original querystring. This needs to be done in the OnActionExecuted (After the action) because some description information are stored in the filterAction.Result.Model.MyDescription.

On the ActionExecutedContext I do not have access to the ActionParameters and the RoutesValues only contains action, controller, id and culture. It doesn't contains any of the other parameters that was included in the querystring.

How can I preserve the ActionParameters from the OnActionExecuting to the OnActionExecuted?

Controller:

```
[ReportHistoryLink]
public ActionResult Index(int id, DateTime at, string by)
{
    var model = new ReportModel();
    model.ReportDescription = "Some logic get the ReportDescription";
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

ActionFilter:

```
public class ReportHistoryLinkAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var model = (IModelWithReportDescription)((ViewResult)filterContext.Result).Model;
        var description = model.ReportDescription;

        var boxedId = filterContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
        var id = Convert.ToInt32(boxedId);
        if (id != 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetDescription))
        {
            var link = new HistoryLink
            {
                Id = id,
                Description = description,
                Route = filterContext.RouteData.Values  //This doesn't contains the "at and by parameters"
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["id"]
```

Comment: also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518827/getting-the-values-of-action-parameters-within-an-action-filter). hope helps someone.

Comment: Just bear in mind that this can get values that don't even exist as parameters in the current action method! To get those you do `filterContext.ActionParameters["parameterName"]`.

Comment: filterContext does not contain ActionParameters

Comment: @stephone is right. `QueryString` contains strings. Action parameters are parsed into types.

Comment: I don't know why that is not working for me. It is empty all time the querystring and I'm sending parameters.